# Nextcord Fight Command Organization and Suggestions

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

I created an extremely basic fight command in Nextcord. The command is like so:

```
/fight [your character] [your weapon] [your enemy] [enemy's weapon]
```

Each character and weapon is assigned their own strength, speed, and defense stats. And the stats are all added up to find their final stat. Then it does the same for the enemy and it calculates the outcome.

What I would like to do is make my code more organized, and the command more intricate. For example giving someone who has overall lower statistics a chance to win due to being faster. Currently I feel like a lot of the entering is manual so making new characters is very tedious. Does anyone have any suggestions?
Also, I am planning on giving certain characters and weapons negative values for certain stats. Such as giving the katana negative defense and spork negative strength.

My current code for the fight cog:

```
class fight(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    testServerID = 948362430256410685

    @nextcord.slash_command(name = "fight", description = "does fight stuff idk", guild_ids=[testServerID])
    async def fight(self, interaction: Interaction, char1, weapon1, char2, weapon2):
    # Speed            
        sDre = 3
        sHenry = 4
        sSonic = 10
        sNub = 3
        sGod = 5
        sPewdiepie = 6
    # Strength
        stDre = 3
        stHenry = 6
        stSonic = 5
        stNub = 4
        stGod = 5
        sPewdiepie = 6
    # Defense
        dDre = 6
        dHenry = 7
        dSonic = 5
        dNub = 5
        dGod = 5
        dPewdiepie = 6

    # WeaponStats
    # Speed
        sKatana = 6
        sKnife = 4
        sSpork = 1
        sNokia = 0
        sDiamondSword = 6
    # Strength
        stKatana = 3
        stKnife = 7
        stSpork = 6
        stNokia = 3
        stDiamondSword = 4
    # Defense
        dKatana = 1
        dKnife = 2
        dSpork = 2
        dNokia = 9
        dDiamondSword = 2

    # Char1
        if char1 == 'Dre':
            fighterstat = sDre+stDre+dDre
        if char1 == 'Henry':
            fighterstat = sHenry+stHenry+dHenry
        if char1 == 'Sonic':
            fighterstat = sSonic+stSonic+dSonic
        if char1 == 'Nub':
            fighterstat = sNub+stNub+dNub
        if char1 == 'God':
            fighterstat = sGod+stGod+dGod
        if char1 == 'Pewdiepie':
            fighterstat = sDre+stDre+dDre

    # Weapon1
        if weapon1 == 'Katana':
            weaponstat = sKatana+stKatana+dKatana
        if weapon1 == 'Knife':
            weaponstat = sKnife+stKnife+dKnife
        if weapon1 == 'Spork':
            weaponstat = sSpork+stSpork+dSpork
        if weapon1 == 'Nokia':
            weaponstat = sNokia+stNokia+dNokia
        if weapon1 == 'DiamondSword':
            weaponstat = sDiamondSword+stDiamondSword+dDiamondSword

    # Weapon2
        if weapon2 == 'Katana':
            eweaponstat = sKatana+stKatana+dKatana
        if weapon2 == 'Knife':
            eweaponstat = sKnife+stKnife+dKnife
        if weapon2 == 'Spork':
            eweaponstat = sSpork+stSpork+dSpork
        if weapon2 == 'Nokia':
            eweaponstat = sNokia+stNokia+dNokia
        if weapon2 == 'DiamondSword':
            eweaponstat = sDiamondSword+stDiamondSword+dDiamondSword

    # Char1
        if char2 == 'Dre':
            efighterstat = sDre+stDre+dDre
        if char2 == 'Henry':
            efighterstat = sHenry+stHenry+dHenry
        if char2 == 'Sonic':
            efighterstat = sSonic+stSonic+dSonic
        if char2 == 'Nub':
            efighterstat = sNub+stNub+dNub
        if char2 == 'God':
            efighterstat = sGod+stGod+dGod
        if char2 == 'Pewdiepie':
            efighterstat = sDre+stDre+dDre

        fFighter = fighterstat+weaponstat
        fEnemy = efighterstat+eweaponstat

        win = 'Your character has won the duel! Excellent choice'
        lose = 'Your character has lost, try again'
        tie = 'You both are equals, try different weapons'

        if fFighter < fEnemy:
            await interaction.response.send_message(lose)
        if fFighter > fEnemy:
            await interaction.response.send_message(win)
        if fFighter == fEnemy:
            await interaction.response.send_message(tie)

        print(fFighter)
        print(fFighter)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(fight(client))
```

Comment: keep values in dictionaries. So later you can do `fighterstat = Speed[char1] + Strange[char1] + Defense[char1]`. And if you add new character to dictionaries then you don't have to change it.

Comment: there is good rule to use `CamelCaseNames` for classes - `class Fight`. It helps to recognize class in code. More: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would keep data in dictionaries

```
class Fight(commands.Cog):
    
    testServerID = 948362430256410685

    char_speed = {           
        'Dre': 3,
        'Henry': 4,
        'Sonic': 10,
        'Nub': 3,
        'God': 5,
        'Pewdiepie': 6,
    }        

    char_strength = {
        'Dre': 3,
        'Henry': 6,
        'Sonic': 5,
        'Nub': 4,
        'God': 5,
        'Pewdiepie': 6,
    }

    char_defense = {
        'Dre': 6,
        'Henry': 7,
        'Sonic': 5,
        'Nub': 5,
        'God': 5,
        'Pewdiepie': 6,
    }

    # ... other ...
```

then you could write it as

```
@nextcord.slash_command(name="fight", description="does fight stuff idk", guild_ids=[testServerID])
async def fight(self, interaction: Interaction, char1, weapon1, char2, weapon2):

    if (char1 in self.char_speed) and (char1 in self.char_strength) and (char1 in self.char_defense): 
        fighterstat = self.char_speed[char1] + self.char_strange[char1] + self.char_defense[char1]
    else:
        print('Unknow char1:', char1)

    # ... other ...
```

and if you would need more characters then you would have to only add values to dictionares - without changing rest of code.

You could even read data from file. Or you could add discord command which adds character.

---

EVentually you could group by character and weapon

```
class Fight(commands.Cog):
    
    testServerID = 948362430256410685
    
    character = {
        'Dre':   {'speed': 3,  'strength': 3, 'defense': 6},
        'Henry': {'speed': 4,  'strength': 6, 'defense': 7},
        'Sonic': {'speed': 10, 'strength': 5, 'defense': 5},
        'Nub':   {'speed': 3,  'strength': 4, 'defense': 5},
        'God':   {'speed': 5,  'strength': 5, 'defense': 5},
        'Pewdiepie': {'speed': 6, 'strength': 6, 'defense': 6},
    }        

    weapon = {
        'Katana': {'speed': 6,  'strength': 3, 'defense': 1},
        # ... code ...
    }
```

and then it could be simpler

```
@nextcord.slash_command(name="fight", description="does fight stuff idk", guild_ids=[testServerID])
async def fight(self, interaction: Interaction, char1, weapon1, char2, weapon2):

    if char1 in self.character:
        data = self.character[char1]
        fighterstat = data['speed'] + data['strange'] + data['defense']
    else:
        print('Unknow char1:', char1)


    # ... other ...
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! Could you also help me with adding a bit of randomness to the command? For example, if someone had overall lower statistics, but had a very high speed. They would have a chance of outspeeding the opponent?

Comment: you have module `random` and `random.randint(a, b)` to get random value in some range a...b. OR `random.choice(list)` to get random value from list. Doc: [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)